# Stock market APIs that include European and ETF market?

Tags: stocks, etf, europe

I have tried these options:

- [GoogleFinances](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en)
- YahooFinances API
- [iexcloud](https://iexcloud.io)
- [alphavantage](https://www.alphavantage.co)
- [worldtradingdata](https://www.worldtradingdata.com)

For the first two (Google and Yahoo) looks like the API is deprecated and can not be used programatically any more

For the rest I don't found on their DB any of the Symbols of my portfolio:

```
| Produkt          | Symbol/ISIN  | Ticker Symbol | Exchange Symbol |
|------------------|--------------|---------------|-----------------|
| ISHARES EUROPE   | IE00B1YZSC51 | IMEU          | EAM             |
| ISHR PAC XJPN A  | IE00B52MJY50 | CPXJ          | EAM             |
| VANGUARD FTSE EM | IE00B3VVMM84 | VFEM          | EAM             |
| VANGUARD S&P500  | IE00B3XXRP09 | VUSA          | EAM             |
```

What options exist that provide programatic (API) price information for stock ticker from the European/ETF market?

Comment: Interesting question. I was surprised to see that these APIs don't simply work with the ISINs; there always has to be some calculatiuon to identify a paper.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are specifically off-topic here. Sorry.